# To calculate the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $E$ and $F$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $$G = \{\begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{2n} \mid X+Y \in E, Y \in F\}$$. I am trying to calculate the dimension of $G$, and I suspect that $\text{dim } G = \text{dim } E + \text{dim } F$, but I don't see how to justify it. Thanks if someone wants to help me.

Comment: Yes. Transform the set with a linear isomorphism into the product $E\times F$. Then it follows

Comment: I am thinking about this  $f: E \times F \to G$ with $f(X,Y) = \begin{pmatrix} X+Y \\ Y \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Looks good. Now show that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Tzimmo Well, it is not quite right: domain and codomain should be changed.

Comment: @psl2Z Whoops, I read a minus there instead of a plus.

Comment: I have a problem with the surjection because I need to demonstrate that if $X+Y \in E$, then $X-Y \in E

Comment: I think we should rather consider $f: E \times F \to G$ with $f(X,Y) = \begin{pmatrix} X-Y \\ Y \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you already answered your question in the comments.

Let $f:G\to E\times F$ be a linear map defined by
$$f\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=(X+Y,Y).$$
Let $f^{-1}: E\times F\to G$ be a linear map defined by
$$f^{-1}(W,Z)=\begin{pmatrix}W-Z\\Z\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can show that
$$f^{-1}\circ f\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=f^{-1}(X+Y,Y)=\begin{pmatrix}(X+Y)-Y\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix};$$
$$f\circ f^{-1}(W,Z)=f\begin{pmatrix}W-Z\\Z\end{pmatrix}=\left((W-Z)+Z,Z\right)=(W,Z).$$
Thus, we have $f^{-1}\circ f=\operatorname{Id}_G$ and $f\circ f^{-1}=\operatorname{Id}_{E\times F}$, which means that $f:G\to E\times F$ is an isomorphism. Therefore,
$$\dim(G)=\dim( E\times F)=\dim(E)+\dim(F).$$

Comment: thank you so much